How can I clean fungus in my lens, and/or prevent fungus from spreading in the lens?
I just recently saw my lens having fungus on lower front glass. It doesn't affect the output but I'm just going to ask that since that there is a fungus present in the lens now, will it become worse if I cover it with front lens cap and add more silica gel in the box? Or should I not cover it with front lens cap so the lens will have light/ artificial light? (rear lens cap included ofc)

The UV component in natural sunlight inhibits the growth of fungi. Leave the lens cap off and let the lens get natural sunlight on a regular basis, such as a few hours each week, and the fungi should not increase.

Existing damage to coatings or adhesives is known to persist.

@davolfman Of course, but it sounds like in this case the fungus has just appeared and there probably isn't much, if any, etching of the lens elements yet. It usually takes a while for fungi to noticeably damage the glass.
